# Convert from json to xml without ordering the data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicttoxml

Anyone know how to convert from json to xml but keeping the data in the same order (without ordering them). I tried Json2xml, dicttoxml and dict2xml but all of them are ordering the data.
Please I need help, thank you!
For example: from dict2xml import dict2xml

```
data = {
  'b': 1,
  'a': 7
}

print (dict2xml(data, wrap="all", indent="  "))
```

Is giving an output:

```
<all>
  <a>7</a>
  <b>1</b>
</all>
```

Comment: Can you give an example ? The [official example](https://github.com/delfick/python-dict2xml) keeps the order. Btw. what's your Python version ?

Comment: I updated the question to include example, py version is 3.5.2

Comment: Dictionaries do not preserve order in Py<3.7. You need to convert them into a [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer the point is that I dont want to save them in order. I just want them to be in the same order that I eneterd them

Comment: Easiest would be to switch to Python3.6, to [preserve insert order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)